# define arrowMethod in ES6 class

Tags: javascript

```
class Test{
  fn(){}
  someName = 'test';
  arrowfn=()=>{}
}
const a = new Test();
```

I have a question. Where are the 'someName' and 'arrowfn'? in the Test.prototype, i can't find them.
the instance a can execute arrowfn method and gets value of someName.
And another question, How to rewrite Test as ES5 version? thanks any help.

[image]

Comment: Because the way `someName` and `arrowfn` are defined, they will not be on the Object 's prototype but on the instance.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`someName` and `arrowfn` are fields. They are generated on each instance by the constructor. They are not in the prototype. Your code is essentially the same as:

```
class Test{
  fn(){}
  constructor(){
    this.someName = 'test';
    this.arrowfn=()=>{}
  }
}
const a = new Test();
```

Comment: I got it, thank you. I know how to rewrite in es5.